# как правильно подключить static функцию в хидер и cpp&

Tags: c++

есть такой cpp файл

```
#include"Object1.h"

using namespace std;

Object1::~Object1(){
    
}
Object1::Object1(){

}
static Object* create_func()
{
    Object1 *temp1 = new Object1(); 
    return temp1;
}
```

и такой h файл

```
#pragma once
#include"factory.h"
#include<string>



class Object1: public Object{
public:
  Object1();
  std::string getName(){return "Object1";}
  ~Object1();
};
```

Нужно ли в h файле объявить функцию `static Object* create_func()`
В институте сказали, что это потенциально опасно, но опасно чем? И почему нельзя объявить в хидере. Препод очень любит с.

Comment: ¿Известно ли вам, для чего в данном контексте служит ключевое слово `static`?

Comment: да, мне нужно, чтобы эта функция была только в этом файле

Comment: В результате вы получите такую функцию в каждом файле, где будет включен этот заголовочный файл... Опасно это или нет - смотрите сами :)

Comment: ¿Известно ли вам, для чего нужно объявлять функции? @Harry Ну вот не надо выдумывать страшилки со смайликами. В результате ничего не произойдет, хоть действие сие лишено смысла.

Comment: Да, это предварительное объявление. Оно сообщает о существовании функции компилятору до его определения.

Comment: ¿Ну вот - а для чего компилятору может понадобиться узнавать о существовании этой функции каждый раз при включении заголовочного файла, если это функция будет использоваться только в одной единице трансляции (.cpp файле)?

Comment: @user7860670 Формально компилятор может скомпилировать эту функцию в каждом cpp-файле. Особенно если она таки вызывается :) Да, оптимизатор скорее всего ее просто уберет, если она не вызвана в пределах файла. Уберите слово `static` - и вы тут же получите нарушение ODR, нет? на тот случай, чтоб эта функция была единственной - ее надо объявить как `inline`.

Comment: @Harry Компилятор мог бы ее скомпилировать и т.д, если бы речь шла об определении функции в заголовочном файле. А вопрос был про объявление.

Comment: @user7860670 Лично я понял вопрос так, что что будет, если вынести `static Object* create_func()
{
    Object1 *temp1 = new Object1(); 
    return temp1;
}` из cpp-файла в заголовочный.

Answer (score 0):

Внутри класса **static** функция означает использование функции **без** объекта.

Вне определения класса - как-всегда, много экзепляров в каждой единице компиляции. И это приводит к увеличении размера исполняемого файла.

Скорее всего, эту функцию удобнее расположить во внутрь класса :

.h :

```
class Object1: public Object{
public:
  Object1();
  std::string getName(){return "Object1";}
  ~Object1();

// если очень надо, то приватно
// private:
  static Object1* create_func();

};
```

.cpp :

```
Object1* Object1::create_func()
{
    Object1 *temp1 = new Object1(); 
    return temp1;
}
```

использование :

```
Object1 * o = Object1::create_func();
```

---

Если функция не внутри класса, то нужно писать код во внутрь хедера :

.h :

```
static Object* create_func();

static Object* create_func()
{
    Object1 *temp1 = new Object1(); 
    return temp1;
}
```

чтобы это определение функции было видно во всех компилируемых **.cpp** файлах.

---

Опасность другого подхода будет если вы предварительно объявите **static**, а потом сделаете функцию в **.cpp** файле.

.h :

```
static    Object* create_func();
```

.cpp :

```
Object* create_func(){
  ..}
```

Эта функция будет видна только в одном **.cpp** файле, где она написана. Из других **.cpp** файлов запуск этой функции приведёт к ошибке : "*нет определения данной функции*". Так как её код должен присутствовать во всех **.cpp** файлах.

Answer (score -1):

Теоретически оно вообще не должно работать. В теории эту функцию нельзя юзать в другом .cpp.

Тоесть если есть файл с

```
Object* create_func()
{
    Object1 *temp1 = new Object1(); 
    return temp1;
}
```

То в другои файле можно написать

```
Object* create_func();
```

И использовать её, а со статиком такое не прокатит.

Но вообще ни разу такое не встречал.

У метода часто видел, там `static` означает, что функция работает без инстанса класса.

Возможно имеет смысл inline? inline приписать можно, чтобы определение в хедер впихнуть.

Опасно тут то, что неясно что начудит компилятор и коллеги, увидев такой статик.

Может просто убрать статик и объявить функцию?

```
 Object* create_func();
```

В таком виде всё обычно и пишут программы.